# CSS not applying to <span> class

Tags: html, css

I am creating a personal website that has a resume page where I list my education. I'd like to format the university name separately from the rest of the text.

The HTML and CSS as below:

```css
.resEducInst {
       font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="resEduc">
       <p>
          <span class=“resEducInst”>University 1</span> 
          ...
       </p>
       <p>
          <span class=“resEducInst”>University 2</span>
          ...
       </p>
    </div>
```

This does not work. The span text is no different from the rest of the paragraph text. When I select the div ID, the entire text is bolded, so it's possible, but not so when just selecting the span class. What am I missing?

Comment: Fix the quotes and you should be good to go. `“` should be `"`

Answer (score 6):

Code is working, but your version is using `“` around `resEducInst` class, instead of `"`. Refer to the code below.

```css
.resEducInst {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="resEduc">
   <p>
      <span class="resEducInst">University 1</span> 
      ...
   </p>
   <p>
      <span class="resEducInst">University 2</span>
      ...
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

hahhah. You're not going to be happy to hear this but have a look at the quotation marks around your span classes.

They should be " but you have “ which is not the correct character. Easy mistake if you copied code from somewhere online.

I tried it and problem solved. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEQLTXN9RWVF

Comment: Correct! I copied from online. I wrote the css code by hand and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Here.!

Double Quotes in span caused it..

```css
.resEducInst {
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="resEduc">
  <p>
    <span class='resEducInst'>University 1</span> ...
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class='resEducInst'>University 2</span> ...
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are fine. It was just the style of quotes that were used that were the problem.

Comment: Just copypasted it in my editor and thought so.. You ll be correct!